# Spring automatically loads context file from package

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Spring automatically loads context file from package (Without adding listener).
I can't add the following listener in the web.xml. If I add them, it shows error.Is there any option for spring, which will automatically scan the package and loads the XML.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfiglocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:com/preprogrammer/recruiterbox/config/dao-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: There should not be an error. Which error do you get?

Comment: what you mentioned thats exactly correct

Comment: @Henry This is the error i am getting : SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] . But, I mentioned the context xml in the context param, correct ..?

Comment: You misspelled `contextConfigLocation`, note the capital L.

Comment: @Henry Ok.That's right. It's working now. But, if i don't add the listener and context param, it still works.How is that possible ..?

Comment: Do you have a class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext.xml" />
```

You could import it in your servert.xml file .

If your XML is available in classpath spring will take care of it. No need of listener .